# Two apparently equal numbers evaluate as False when I ask if they are equal

Tags: differential-equations, physics, event-detection

I am solving numerically a differential equation and trying to use `WhenEvent[θ[t] == θ0, "StopIntegration"]` but it doesn't stop until the last limit.

```
μ = 1;
v0 = 2;
r = 1;
vc = Sqrt[(r*
      g*2 (2 μ^2 - 1 + 
        Sqrt[μ^2 + 1]*E^(-2 μ*ArcTan[μ])))/(1 + 
      4 μ^2)];
vp[θ_] := 
 v0^2/(r*g) E^(2 μ*θ) + ((4 μ^2 - 2) (Cos[θ] - 
        E^(2 μ*θ)) - 6 μ*Sin[θ])/(4 μ^2 + 
     1)
np[θ_] := Cos[θ] - vp[θ]
θ0 = 
 If[v0 < vc, θ /. 
   FindRoot[vp[θ] == 0, {θ, Pi/12, 0, Pi}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 10], θ /. 
   FindRoot[np[θ] == 0, {θ, Pi/12, 0, Pi/2}, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 10]]
sol = NDSolve[{θ''[t] == 
     g/r*Sin[θ[t]] - μ/
        r ((g*Cos[θ[t]]) - r*(θ'[t])^2), θ'[0] ==
      v0/r, θ[0] == 0, 
    WhenEvent[θ[t] == θ0, 
     "StopIntegration"]}, θ, {t, 0, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 5];
Plot[Evaluate[θ[t] /. sol], 
 Evaluate[Flatten[{t, θ["Domain"] /. sol}]]]
```

It doesn't stop even if I change `PrecisionGoals`. But I see that my `θ0` seems to be actually the `MaxValue` in the solution

```
N[θ0, 5]
FindMaxValue[Evaluate[θ[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.5}]
N[FindMaxValue[Evaluate[θ[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 0.5}], 
  3] == θ0
```

Even when they evaluate as non equal.

So, I tried to change WhenEvent as `θ[t] >= θ0`, but still doen't stop there.

Comment: Have you considered using a less stringent condition like `Abs[θ[t] - θ0] <= tol`, where `tol` is some convenient tiny value?

Comment: It works, thanks so much. Also, if `tol` is smaller, it doesn't stop again.